# C# - What is Culture-Specific?

Tags: c#, .net, string, resharper

I'm quite new at C#. ReSharper warned me that using "string.IndexOf" is culture-specific. What exactly is being culture-specific?

Comment: Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Culture is referring to the language for example American English (en-us) and British English (en-gb) (Obviously the same language but different cultures as far as .NET is concerned). The reason it might matter when using "string.IndexOf" is because certain characters (think characters with accents and umlauts) get treated differently in different cultures. There aren't enough unicode values to represent every character in every language so within certain culture settings certain character combinations (such as an 'a' followed by an umlaut) are combined into a single character but in other culture settings they may not be. So using "string.IndexOf" on a string with an umlaut might yield different results depending on the set culture. But in most circumstances, especially if you're just learning, default behavior of the string class will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Resharaper is a extension to follow some coding standard if any method  accepting culture as a overload.then it is very good practice to provide these features in your code

```
comparisonType
```

parameter specifies to search for the value parameter using the current or invariant culture, using a case-sensitive or case-insensitive search, and using word or ordinal comparison rules.

[More Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx)